# Which preposition should I use? "until", "through" or "as of"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

If I want to say, please send me the forecast until July next year. Can I replace "until" with "through" or "as of"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your context, ***until*** means you want the forecast covering the period ***between now and next July*** (possibly including the month of July itself - that detail is ambiguous). Strictly speaking it's not syntactically valid to use ***through***, but that would probably be understood as referring to ***just the single month of next July***. And using ***as of*** would also be unusual / invalid, but might be understood as meaning ***starting from next July*** (for an unspecified length of time after that).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is "through" really not valid? To me that seems to be the best answer, actually conveying that the forecast should cover the time period up to and including July. Also, shouldn't your comment be an answer?

Comment: ...note that it makes a difference whether what you're asking for is *a single forecast*, or "regular" forecasts (for example, one every month from now until next July). Feasibly ***through*** could be considered "valid" for the "regular monthly updated forecasts" sense, but even then I'd expect ***through until***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This may be a localization difference, as I see you are in the UK, but I cannot recall ever encountering "through until" in all of my (too) many years of education.

Comment: @Tashus: My substantive point is that ***through*** isn't really valid here at all (though it's hard to say, since we don't know whether we're talking about a single forecast or regular repeated forecasts). Maybe I should have suggrsted ***through to July*** (but it being a somewhat US-style usage, perhaps I should have written [***thru** to next June*).](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thru+to+next+june%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the source of my confusion is that I see no reason why **through** shouldn't be valid here. My understanding of the question (the literal text, not the post on ell) is that the asker wants a forecast spanning from some starting point (either now or some understood time based on omitted context) up to and including July. Perhaps we have different understandings of the question, but if not, then I don't see why **through** would not be valid. **Through** is exactly the word that I would use and would expect to see or hear.

Comment: @Tashus: The problem with ***through*** here is that there's no obvious way to differentiate between an intended meaning of 1) *from now until the start of July*, 2) *from now until the end of July*, and 3) *from the start of July to the end of July*. Take a statement like *I'll be working there through summer*, for example. The most natural interpretation would be ***throughout*** summer (which I might say in January, months before I start work there). If I meant ***from now until*** (ambiguous whether summer is included ***or*** excluded) I'd normally have to say ***thru [un]till***.

Answer (score 2):

**Until**: Continue this action up to the specified point, then stop. So, "please send me the forecast **until** July next year" will get you the forecasts up to June 30th next year, then they will stop.

**Through**: Continue this action up to the END of the specified point, then stop. "Please send me the forecast **through** July next year" will get you the forecasts up to July 31st next year, then they will stop.

**As of**: Begin this action at the specified point. "Please send me the forecast **as of** July next year" would probably get you a confused message, since it is normally used to refer to past data. For example, "What are our total sales **as of** March 15th?" would refer to sales data up to the point of March 15th of the current year, even if more data is available.

There are some alternatives to **until** in this context; "Up to" would be the closest. However, **until** is probably the correct word to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "through", in the sense of [definition 4 c in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through).

> Please send me the forecast through July of next year.

If you use "until July" it sounds like you are asking the person to start sending the forecast now and to send it continuously, only stopping in July.

If you use "as of July" it sounds like you want a forecast that will be made in July, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It would probably be helpful not to use "until" in your description of what "until July" means. As written, it's a bit circular.

Comment: In a context where the OP is implicitly asking for "valid" usages, I don't think we should be endorsing plain ***through*** without ***until***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I also replied to your comment on the question, but I'm not sure to what you referring by "endorsing plain ***through*** without ***until***." I wasn't even aware of that option/distinction.